# How to get C# Cmdlet Parameter HelpMessage to show up in `Get-Help`

Tags: c#, powershell, powershell-cmdlet

I have started a PowerShell cmdlet and want to supply the help message for a parameter. I've tried using `ParameterAttribute.HelpMessage` for this:

```
[Cmdlet(VerbsCommon.Get, "Workspace", SupportsShouldProcess = true)]
public class GetWorkspace : PSCmdlet
{
    [Parameter(
        Mandatory = true,
        Position = 1,
        HelpMessage = "The path to the root directory of the workspace.")]
    public string Path { get; set; }

    protected override void ProcessRecord()
    {
        base.ProcessRecord();
    }
}
```

But when I use the PowerShell `Get-Help` command, it does not show the HelpMessage for the parameter:

```
get-help Get-Workspace -det

NAME
    Get-Workspace

SYNTAX
    Get-Workspace [-Path] <string> [-WhatIf] [-Confirm]  [<CommonParameters>]


PARAMETERS
    -Confirm

    -Path <string>

    -WhatIf

    <CommonParameters>
        This cmdlet supports the common parameters: Verbose, Debug,
        ErrorAction, ErrorVariable, WarningAction, WarningVariable,
        OutBuffer, PipelineVariable, and OutVariable. For more information, see
        about_CommonParameters (http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkID=113216).


ALIASES
    None


REMARKS
    None
```

When writing a cmdlet in PowerShell script I can add a help message for parameters using this syntax:

```
<#
.Parameter Path
The local path to the root folder of the workspace.
#>
```

But what is the equivalent in a C# cmdlet?

Comment: Take a look at the _"XmlDoc2CmdletDoc"_ NuGet package (and some RedGate blog postings).  It lets you take standard C# XML Comments and turn it into amazing Get-Help text

Answer (score 5):

You're doing it absolutely right!

You just need to inspect the `-Full` view or get help for the specific parameter with `-Parameter`:

```
PS C:\> Get-Help Get-Workspace -Parameter Path

-Path <string>
    The path to the root directory of the workspace.

    Required?                    true
    Position?                    1
    Accept pipeline input?       false
    Parameter set name           (All)
    Aliases                      None
    Dynamic?                     false
```

Comment: Thanks. But I don't have to do that with ps1 cmdlets, I think. Just `Get-Help Get-Workspace -det` is enough to see the parameter help message. Is that not achievable for C# cmdlets?