# Document powershell script parameter without repeating in comment and HelpMessage

Tags: powershell, dry

Is it possible to specify both the `HelpMessage` and **comment-based-help** content for a powershell script's parameter *without* repeating the text (DRY)?

### Test script

```
# .SYNOPSIS
# a thing for testing help
[CmdletBinding()]
param (
    # COMMENT-MESSAGE-HERE-NOT-DRY
    [parameter(Mandatory=$true, HelpMessage="HELP-MESSAGE-HERE-NOT-DRY")]
    $thing
)

echo $thing
```

### HelpMessage output

```
~\Documents> .\erm.ps1
cmdlet erm.ps1 at command pipeline position 1
Supply values for the following parameters:
(Type !? for Help.)
thing: !?
HELP-MESSAGE-HERE-NOT-DRY
thing: oh well
oh well
~\Documents>
```

### get-help output

```
~\Documents> help .\erm.ps1 -detailed
...
PARAMETERS
    -thing <Object>
        COMMENT-MESSAGE-HERE-NOT-DRY
```

## Related questions

- [How do I get help messages to appear for my Powershell script parameters?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5237723/how-do-i-get-help-messages-to-appear-for-my-powershell-script-parameters#30377868)
- [How to get C# Cmdlet Parameter HelpMessage to show up in `Get-Help`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32721832/how-to-get-c-sharp-cmdlet-parameter-helpmessage-to-show-up-in-get-help)

## Related articles

- https://powershell.org/2013/05/06/a-helpful-message-about-helpmessage/
- [TechNet - WTFM: Writing the Fabulous Manual](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff458353.aspx)

---

While it may not be used by many people I think if it's there and people can find it I should populated it. But I don't want to damage maintainability.

I'm guessing the answer is no, but thought I'd ask.

Comment: Answer is "no, not really" - as soon as you include comment-based help in the script, `HelpMessage` gets ignored completely by `Get-Help`. If you were to remove the `SYNOPSIS` comments, the `HelpMessage` value would be shown